# Can I use loopj async HTTP client to send data to a PHP page?

Tags: java, php, android, android-handler, android-async-http

I have successfully installed the loopj async http client and I am having this issue whilst executing this code:

```
 protected void PostData(Integer Question_ID,Integer ResponseChosen_ID) throws IOException {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        final RequestParams params1 = new RequestParams();
        params1.add("Question_ID",Question_ID.toString());
        client.post("http://10.0.2.2:443/SwlLogin.php", params1, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                System.out.print(params1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });
```

Error:

> Synchronous ResponseHandler used in AsyncHttpClient. You should create your response handler in a looper thread or use SyncHttpClient instead.

Is this because of the UI thread but the whole point of using this client is that it can bypass the UI thread exception and execute a http request?

There is no logcat.

Any advice on how to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which part of the error message is unclear? It says to use a looper or `SyncHttpClient`.

Comment: theres nothing to report in the logcat nothing fails no exceptions no errors nothing

Comment: i have put a log.d around the onSuccess method call but nothing gets printed just prints a status code of 200 on the android popup

Answer (score 2):

You can call the `PostData()` with the following workaround

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable(
   {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        postData();
    }
})) ;
```

It is exactly a UI thread issue.

Comment: have i misunderstood this client completely can i use this client to send data to a php webpage correct?

Comment: Yes you can, it's a widely used library for networking

Comment: ok. so would you have any ideas of why i cant get my data to display on the php side?

Comment: I dont know what more else to try now as ive tried the built in http client and ive tried a third party one something tells me something is blocking the socket perhaps or something i tried it on a production environment also

Comment: May be your windows/linux firewall

Comment: i have a feeling its that not sure how to bypass that.

Comment: Within the same network, what happens if you open the url in the browser or the Postman, for example ?

Comment: i can get it to easily no problems in the browser

Comment: is it possible for me to bypass the php session?

Comment: what is very interesting i can send data from the php app to android

Answer (score 1):

I used loopJ AsyncHttpClient for several projects, Can I know the whole code/class that you are implementing the loopJ?

You should implement you client like this if you are expecting String from your php

```
client.post("http://10.0.2.2:443/SwlLogin.php", params1, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", responseString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", responseString);
        }
    });
```

Comment: just this method in the mainActivity class on android

Comment: Maybe you are running this method inside a running thread in your mainActivity ?

Comment: yeh i am but the request should still be executed though right?

Comment: Then use `SyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();` in your postData() method, loopJ AsyncHttpClient determine what thread is running.

Comment: do i need to read the data into a reader or can i just display using php superglobals? or do i need to use JSON

Comment: Are you expecting something response from the php ? What is the format of the response ? Is it JSON format ? or Just string ?

Comment: no i dont wish to send data back to android from php. just php to get data to process further if that make sense just a string at the moment

Comment: If you are passing only the value to php, just make sure that the params key in your android code and params in your php code is exactly same.

Comment: it is the same but nothing is displayed

Comment: displayed where ? Maybe there is an error/exception in your logcat, just post it here.

Comment: there is no exception being thrown only when i change url to localhost

Comment: im trying to display it on the php page

Comment: Do you API/webservices for Android ? Maybe your php code is not API construct. You should know about using API.

Comment: Just check this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/ and this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/

Comment: thats not what i have ive changed the way i have done things twice as well. I dont need to use API what i have should work as i followed the docs just the php side is not working or maybe you could be right

Comment: the reason for no exception is because it is actually working but i cant display on webpage. is it because of my host? i cant use localhost but shall i try a production environment and launch a website and then try it?

Answer (score 0):

php code :

```
ob_start();
error_reporting(0);

var_dump($_REQUEST);
var_dump(headers_list());
```